# Flatlist not rendering items (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native

Hi guys I have this data

```
{
    "data": {
        "image": [
            {
                "item_image": "Sample Data"
            },
            {
                "item_image": "Sample Data 2"
            }
        ],
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "promotion_categoryname": "Cheese Burger Delight",
                "promotion_categoryname_id": 23,
                "promotion_name": "test",
                "promotion_price": 123,
                "promotion_description": "test",
                "promotion_from_date": "2022-03-29",
                "promotion_to_date": "2022-03-31",
                "verified": 0
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "promotion_categoryname": "Sample Beverage",
                "promotion_categoryname_id": 25,
                "promotion_name": "Test",
                "promotion_price": 123,
                "promotion_description": "test",
                "promotion_from_date": "2022-03-29",
                "promotion_to_date": "2022-03-31",
                "verified": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now on my flatlist and setting the data

```
setPromotionData(responseJson.data);

if(promotionData.data.length > 0)
        {
            return (
                <FlatList
                    data={promotionData}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                                <Image 
                                source={{uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ item.image.item_image}}
                                resizeMode='contain'
                                style={{
                                    width:80,
                                    height:80,
                                }}/>
                                <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                                    <Text style={{fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold'}}> {item.data.promotion_categoryname}</Text>
                                    <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:'gray'}}> Php {item.data.promotion_price}.00</Text>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => DeleteItem(item.data.promotion_categoryname_id)}>
                                        <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:'red'}}> Delete</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black', marginBottom:15, marginTop:15}} />
                        </View>
                    )} 
                    keyExtractor={item => item.data.id}
                />
            )
        }
        else
        {
            return (
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20}}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
                    <View>
                        <Text style={{width: 100, textAlign: 'center'}}>No Data</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
                </View>
            );
        }
   }
```

Now the problem here is that I don't know why it is not displaying or rendering the data but when I `console.log()` it has the data same as the data above.

*NOTE: There's no warning or error on the console*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items for the `FlatList` are contained in `promotionData.data` but you are passing `promotionData`, which contains just the `data` object, to the `data` prop of the `FlatList`. Pass the array instead and access the `image` array via the index of the `renderItem` function.

```js
<FlatList
                    data={promotionData.data}
                    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                                <Image 
                                source={{uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ promotionData.image[index].item_image}}
                                resizeMode='contain'
                                style={{
                                    width:80,
                                    height:80,
                                }}/>
                                <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                                    <Text style={{fontSize:20, fontWeight:'bold'}}> {item.promotion_categoryname}</Text>
                                    <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:'gray'}}> Php {item.promotion_price}.00</Text>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => DeleteItem(item.promotion_categoryname_id)}>
                                        <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:'red'}}> Delete</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black', marginBottom:15, marginTop:15}} />
                        </View>
                    )} 
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
```

Comment: Why did I think of passing the array instead.  Thank you . Though I found a way by using 2 flatlist but this one is better . Thank you good sir.

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad it worked out for you.